# Acting when detecting world position

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to get the cube perform an action when its on a defined position but i cant make it work, i can make it show position on the console but cant get the cube to react to the code.

## This is my code

```
import bge

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
            
    own.applyMovement((0.2, 0, 0), True)
    
    pos = own.position
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    z = pos[2]
    
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
    
    if (x = 10):
        own.applyMovement((0, 0, 5), True)
    

main()
```

Comment: It is very rare to hit an exact position unless you explicitly set it. Even then it might not work due to number precision issues. I strongly suggest to check a range as shown in Strapicarus answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: `if (x = 10):` will throw a syntax error. Needs to be `if (x == 10):` for equality.  Check for errors in the system console.  To check approximate equality with floats  use `if abs(x - 10) < TOL:` where TOL is some small tolerance, eg `0.00001`

Comment: You could use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) or expand the test to be `x>9.8 and x<10.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [logical operators](http://apprize.info/php/20lessons/6.html).

[position](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=position#bge.types.KX_GameObject.position) is deprecated use [localPosition](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=local%20position#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localPosition) and [worldPosition](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=world%20position#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldPosition).

```
from bge import logic
cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

own.applyMovement((0.2,0,0),True)

pos = own.worldPosition
x = pos[0]
y = pos[1]
z = pos[2]

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)

if x >= 10:
    own.applyMovement((0,0,5),True)
```

Comment: Please don't promote unnecessary parentheses. `if x >= 10:` is perfectly fine Python code.

Comment: I dont promote that. just copy and paste.

Comment: i was lookig arround and found that [GameObject.position](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=position#bge.types.KX_GameObject.position) is deprecated. Use: localPosition and worldPosition.